# How to modify the /etc/mtab entry created by a custom mount helper such that a custom `umount` is used?

Tags: bash, mount

In response to my question [How to mount a cryptsetup container just with `mount`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52078/863) over at unix.SE, I realized that `mount -t luks` will call the script `mount.luks`, which currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MAPPER=$(mktemp -up /dev/mapper)
cryptsetup luksOpen $1 $(basename $MAPPER)
shift
mount $MAPPER $* || cryptsetup luksClose $(basename $MAPPER)
```

That is, it determines an unused mapper name that [cryptsetup](https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) can use to mount a LUKS/dm-crypt encrypted device (I know the `$*` is dangerously prone to recursion if subtypes are involved, consider this a prototype) after decrypting it (after prompting for the passphrase).

The problem is, the resulting entry of `mount -t luks /dev/hda /mnt/decrypted` in `/etc/mtab` will look something like

```
/dev/mapper/tmp.mpI5ClExf8 on /mnt/decrypted type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=writeback)
```

such that `umount /dev/hda` will fail and `umount /mnt/decrypted` will only unmount the mapper but leave the encrypted device open. The mapper is also rather irrelevant. What I'd like to achieve is having an entry à la

```
/dev/hda on /mnt/decrypted type luks.ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,data=writeback,mapper=/dev/mapper/tmp.mpI5ClExf8)
```

such that `umount` will call `umount.luks`, which may be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
umount $1
cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPER
```

(Again, prototype, this would only treat the `umount /mnt/decrypted` call correctly and `MAPPER` needs to be obtained from the mount option)

So, how does `mount.luks` have to be modified? Directly modifying `/etc/mtab` is certainly a bad idea. (Can e.g. `mount -n` and `mount -f` achieve this somehow?)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I came across it when searching for an answer myself.

If you have a new enough distro, e.g. Fedora 20, then you can modify your mount.luks script to include `'-o helper=luks'`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MAPPER=$(mktemp -up /dev/mapper)
cryptsetup luksOpen $1 $(basename $MAPPER)
shift
mount -o helper=luks $MAPPER $* || cryptsetup luksClose $(basename $MAPPER)
```

umount uses the value of helper to determine the proper umount script to run, similar to the way that mount works with the -t option.

Note: on Fedora 20, /etc/mtab is a symlink to /proc/self/mounts. If you cat /etc/mtab the helper option does not show up. However, if you execute mount with no options, the helper option will appear.

Comment: sounds good, thanks!  Unfortunately I don't have Fedora,  but maybe the respective patch can be applied to other distros as well.